# Sum of Nulls to result a Null in Pivots in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am doing a simple pivot that sums a column and I need the sum(nulls) to be a null (in Google Sheets).  However, I see the pivot table has zero as the value.

In the attached picture case, I expect the group 1s sum to be null, however, pivot returns 0.

Are there any workarounds?  Highly appreciate any help here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the default return value / expected behavior when using the SUM() function in adding blank cells will always be 0. Based from the post [Comparing blank cell with a cell containing '0' is equating to TRUE all of a sudden](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/75135122?hl=en&msgid=75156197), 0 and null are both NOT TRUE, thus, they are the same.

### Workaround Solution: Add a Calculated Field to the Values Section

You may use the following formula for the Calculated Field formula:

`=if(sum(B),sum(B),"NULL")`

However, this is only a workaround and will display a string `NULL` and not the actual null value whenever the sum is zero. The downside to this is that it will not display the value 0 even if the cells have actual values and it just happens to have a sum of 0.

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: This is helpful solution.  However, the caveat you mentioned is of a big concern -

"The downside to this is that it will not display the value 0 even if the cells have actual values and it just happens to have a sum of 0."

Any thoughts if there's a workaround for this too?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out since the functions are used differently when applied to pivot tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, both an empty cell (or null) and 0 are read as NOT TRUE in Google Sheets and thus are considered the same. (Reference: [Comparing blank cell with a cell containing '0' is equating to TRUE all of a sudden](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/75135122?hl=en&msgid=75156197))